# How do I fill information of a blank row from another row where information is available in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Let's say I have a data frame

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | R3 | P5 |
| A2 | R2 | P4 |
| A2 | NaN | P4 |
| A1 | NaN | NaN |

I want to fill in information for the 3rd and 4th rows from the 2nd and 1st rows since column A values match those two rows. The expected data frame is as follows:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | R3 | P5 |
| A2 | R2 | P4 |
| A2 | **R2** | P4 |
| A1 | **R3** | **P5** |

Can you please help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a single non-NA value per A

You can use a self `merge`:

```
out = df[['A']].merge(df.dropna(), how='left')
```

Or, if there is a chance of duplicated rows:

```
out = df[['A']].merge(df.dropna().drop_duplicates(), how='left')
```

output:

```
    A   B   C
0  A1  R3  P5
1  A2  R2  P4
2  A2  R2  P4
3  A1  R3  P5
```

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do it.

sorting by column 'A', forward filling the null values and then re-sorting by index

```
df.sort_values(['A'] ).ffill().sort_index()
```

```
     A   B   C
0   A1  R3  P5
1   A2  R2  P4
2   A2  R2  P4
3   A1  R3  P5
```